# How to change application version in android studio

Tags: java, android

I would like to change my application version in android studio, I want kitkat android also can use the application, how I change in android studio?

Comment: Do you have an error when you run the app in kitkat? Please post the logcat when you lanunch the app.

Comment: yes, it come out unfortunately,ur application has stopped

Comment: @lunL Copy and paste the error that is being shown in the android studio's console.

Answer (score 0):

In your app's gradle file there are these two properties:

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 26
```

Change them to whatever you like.

Comment: my minSdkVersion 15 .  targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: but also cannot run in kitkat

Comment: IT should support kitkat because kitkat is api numbers 19-20.

Comment: It still come out application has stopped, is because run in emulator?

Comment: It's probably not the version that is giving you problems. It's probably your code. Look in your Android Monitor for your emulator so you can find why your app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You can change application version int `app build.gradle`.

Just like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.keliuyue.kotlin"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: application still stopped

Answer (score 0):

You can change the sdk-version(android version) in Manifest/gradle file.
Although gradle will supersede manifest version values if you update both files.
Check for the sdk version for kitkat and update, or you can update to more recent versions.